# What means the RET=$? in the previous reply?

Tags: shell-script, http, exit-status

In this thread : https://superuser.com/questions/569092/how-to-split-the-http-error-code-from-the-contents-in-curl

What means this part:

```
if [[ $RET -ne 0 ]] ; then
    # if error exit code, print exit code
    echo "Error $RET"
```

I wanted to use it as an error handing but once I have 400 returned it still replies with the part on else just displaying the code, so I am not sure what is this condition about? Is that on https status code or on the request failing ? Please describe in more detail thank you

Sorry I was not able to add comment :( so that is why new question

Comment: Welcome to the site. If you have a follow-up question to a question on another site, please post a more complete extract so that all relevant information is available at a glance. In this case, it is very relevant to the problem what the command _before the `RET=$?`_ was!

Answer (score 1):

Looking at that question you are referring to, we see the following:

```bsh
OUT=$( curl -qSfsw '\n%{http_code}' http://superuser.com ) 2>/dev/null

# get exit code
RET=$?

if [[ $RET -ne 0 ]] ; then
    # if error exit code, print exit code
    echo "Error $RET"
    ...
else
    ...
fi
```

The `$?` builtin is a special variable containing the return code of the previously run command, in this case `curl`. Note that this is the return code *as returned by the `curl` binary to the shell*, **not** the HTTP status code, which in that example is the *console output* of `curl`.

So unless there is some command in between the `OUT= ...` line and the `RET=$?` which overwrites `$?`, it would seem that your `curl` implementation issues a `0` return code even if a `400` error occured (which would be strange, as the `-f` option instructs `curl` to return `22` in this case).

Note btw that the statement

```
OUT=$( curl ... ) 2>/dev/null
```

makes no sense; it should rather be

```
OUT="$( curl ... 2>/dev/null )"
```